# Can't insert into array reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm beginner in reactjs , I'm trying to map an array and get the file and set into another array, but I got an error "TypeError: tmp.book is not iterable".

This is my code

```
import "./App.css";
import { useState } from "react";

function App() {
  const array = [
    {
      no: "3",
      title: "dream",
      singer: "anak",
    },
    {
      no: "4",
      title: "dream",
      singer: "anak",
    },
  ];
  const [tmp, setTmp] = useState({
    food: [
      {
        name: "banana",
        color: "yellow",
        quality: "good",
      },
      {
        name: "apple",
        color: "red",
        quality: "bad",
      },
    ],
    book: [
      {
        no: "1",
        title: "dream",
        singer: "anak",
      },
      {
        no: "2",
        title: "jack",
        singer: "lome",
      },
    ],
  });

  array.map((item) => {
    setTmp([
      ...tmp.book,
      {
        no: item.no,
        title: item.title,
        singer: item.singer,
      },
    ]);
  });

  return "";
}

export default App;
```

[image: This is the result]

Can someone explain to me why I get the error and how to fix it?. Hope you guys understand what I'm asking :D

Comment: Your code looks correct.

Comment: State likely hasn't loaded yet. Why are you mapping and not (1) returning a mapped value and (2) not saving the returned mapped array? Don't put logic like this in the component body, instead use an `useEffect` hook to issue side-effects like mutating some non-state array. The `setTmp` in the component body will trigger infinite looping.

Answer (score 0):

`tmp` is object, but you are trying to set Tmp with the array value.

```js
import "./App.css";
import {
  useState
} from "react";

function App() {
  ...
  useEffect(() => { // iterate `array` inside useEffect
    array.map((item) => {
      const cloned = { ...tmp };
      cloned.book.push({
          no: item.no,
          title: item.title,
          singer: item.singer,
      });
      setTmp(cloned); // set object value since it is set as an object initially
    });
  }, []);

  return "";
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

## Issues

1. Mapping but not returning or saving any mapped value
2. `tmp` state is an object, but you try to mutate it into an array
3. State update in the body of the component will trigger infinite render looping

## Solution

1. Use an `useEffect` hook and update the state
2. Use a functional state update to correctly update from the previous state when using a loop
3. Use `array.prototype.forEach` if *not* actually mapping data

Code

```
React.useEffect(() => {
  array.forEach((item) => {
    setTmp((prev) => ({
      ...prev, // <-- copy all existing state
      book: [ // <-- copy state being updated
        ...prev.book,
        {
          no: item.no,
          title: item.title,
          singer: item.singer
        }
      ]
    }));
  });
}, []);
```

Since the `array` element object shape already matches that of `tmp.book` array elements, you can simply concatenate the two arrays without a loop.

```
React.useEffect(() => {
  setTmp((prev) => ({
    ...prev,
    book: [...prev.book, ...array]
  }));
}, []);
```